# How to Copy data from table with a nested table column

Tags: oracle, insert, nested-table

I have a table that has one of its columns as a nested table.

I want to copy data of this table to another. How do we frame the INSERT clause for this seems challenging:

Consider. The field that is a nested table is phone_list whose type is a user defined type "TBL_PHONE_EXTN" which is a table of "typ_phone_extn".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_phone_extn AS OBJECT
(phone_number VARCHAR2 (20), extension VARCHAR2 (10));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tbl_phone_extn AS TABLE OF typ_phone_extn;
/
```

Obviously below fails: (with a ORA-00904: : invalid identifier)

```
INSERT INTO sch2.sub_pat_address (
          pat_address_id,
          pat_id,
          **phone_list,**
          last_updated_by
)
   SELECT pat_address_id,
          pat_id,
          **phone_list,**
           last_updated_by
     FROM sch1.sub_pat_address ;
```

So i try:

```
   SELECT pat_address_id,
          pat_id,
           **tbl_phone_extn(typ_phone_extn (phone_number,extension)),**
           last_updated_by
     FROM sch1.sub_pat_address, **table(phone_list)** ;
```

What this does is unnest the nested table. So i end up with more records than i want - meaning if a specific pat_address_id had a phone_list of 5 phone,extn combination this gives me 5 records that i cannot and should not be inserting.

So question is, how to keep the nest (nested table column) as-is and insert into the new table? Well, CTAS may be one option but that requires a whole new table instead of a INSERT. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How were created your tables? `INSERT INTO ... tbl_col SELECT tbl_col ...` _should_ work without error. Or do I missed some subtleties?

Comment: Are you sure you got `ORA-00904`, not `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes` or `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`? Are the tables in both schema built referencing their own object/table type, or a common one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`COLLECT` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions031.htm#i1271564) to reassemble the unnested elements into a nested table, casting that back to your actual collection type:

```
   SELECT pat_address_id,
          pat_id,
           cast(collect(typ_phone_extn(phone_number,extension)) as tbl_phone_extn),
           last_updated_by
     FROM sch1.sub_pat_address, table(phone_list)
 GROUP BY pat_address_id, pat_id, last_updated_by;
```

And you can then use that for your insert, obviously.

The only reason I can see you'd have a problem with your original simple insert would be if each schema had its own types and their tables were built using their own types. But then you'd get `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes` or `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` rather than `ORA-00904`.

Even if you have privileges on the types across the schemas, Oracle UDTs have to be the *exact same* type - it's not enough for them to be constructed identically. If they are different entries in `ALL_OBJECTS` then they are not interchangeable.